# Navigation bar on top of the sliding images

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, networking, navigationbar

I can't figure out how to display the navigation bar correctly. I need to set the div which contains the navigation bar on  relative, otherwise the sliding images on the background covers the navigation bar, so this makes all the navigation bar to go all over the place when hovering on it . Anyone knows how to fix it?

[This is how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIhhp.jpg)

[This is what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqqh6.jpg)

```
<html lang ="en-US">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/main1.css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/slide.css" media="all">

    <meta charset="UTF-8></meta>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1150,user-scalable=yes,initial-scale=2.5,maximum-scale=5.0, minimum-scale=1.0"></meta>
<title> MOLEX </title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
</head>
<body>
<style>
* {box-sizing:border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;margin:0}
.mySlides {display:none}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  position: fixed;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  z-index:0;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}



/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor:pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
</style>




<div class="container">
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">News</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  </div>
</div>


<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Notice & Policy</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
        <div class="div3">

</div>
  </div>
</div>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Workflow & MIS</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
          <div class="div2">

</div>
    </div>
  </div> 


<div class="dropdown">
  <img src="css/molex.png" alt="molex" height="40" width="155">
</div>



<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Canteen</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
        <div class="div1">

</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Activity & Organization</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
        <div class="div1">

</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Culture</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
        <div class="div1">

</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>







<ul class="cb-slideshow">
    <li>
        <span>Image 01</span>
        <div>
            <img src="1.jpg" alt="molex" height="100%" width="100%"> 
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><span>Image 01</span>
        <div>
            <img src="2.jpg" alt="molex" height="100%" width="100%"> 
        </div></li>
    <li><span>Image 01</span>
        <div>
            <img src="3.jpg" alt="molex" height="100%" width="100%"> 
        </div></li>
</ul>








<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>







body {background: url(molex-1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;}

.container {
    overflow: visible!important
    background-color: lightgray ;
    background-size: cover;
    width:auto;
    font-family: Arial;
    margin-left: 17%;
    margin-right:22%;
    margin-top: 20px;   
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
}


.container a {

    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;

}

.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;



}

.dropdown1{
float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
margin-left:13%;
margin-top: 14px;

}
.div1 {
    width: 850px;
    height: 400px;

    border: 1px solid red;
display: block;
float:right;
background-color: lightgray;
    opacity: 0.6;

    width: 500px;

}

.div2 {
      width: 850px;
    height: 400px;

    border: 1px solid red;
display: block;
background-color: lightgray;
    opacity: 0.6;

}

.div3 {
    display:none;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: white;

    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    z-index: 20;

}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 17px;    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;

}

.container a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {

    background-color: #FF7575;
}

.dropdown-content {

    display: none;


    min-width: 160px;


}

.dropdown-content a {

    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {

    background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {

    display: block;
}










.cb-slideshow,
.cb-slideshow:after { 
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 0; 
}
.cb-slideshow:after { 
    content: '';
    background: transparent url(../images/pattern.png) repeat top left; 
}


.cb-slideshow li span { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s; 
}


.cb-slideshow li div { 
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    color: #fff;
    animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li div h3 { 
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 240px;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 200px; 
}


.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(1) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/1.jpg) 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/2.jpg);
    animation-delay: 6s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/3.jpg);
    animation-delay: 12s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/4.jpg);
    animation-delay: 18s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/5.jpg);
    animation-delay: 24s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/6.jpg);
    animation-delay: 30s; 
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) div { 
    animation-delay: 6s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) div { 
    animation-delay: 12s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) div { 
    animation-delay: 18s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) div { 
    animation-delay: 24s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) div { 
    animation-delay: 30s; 
}



@keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}


@keyframes titleAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    8% { opacity: 1 }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    19% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}

.no-cssanimations .cb-slideshow li span{
    opacity: 1;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1140px) { 
    .cb-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 140px }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { 
    .cb-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 80px }
}
```

Comment: can you share your code on fiddle or codepen

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6km7gova/#&togetherjs=HmHwMCGgM8